# Prevent folder redirect in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

The following rules are in an htaccess file and need to remain:

```
# GENERAL
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z_0-9\-]+)$ /index.php?page=$1  [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z_0-9\-]+)/$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z_0-9\-]+)/([a-z]+)$ /index.php?page=$1&comp=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z_0-9\-]+)/([a-z]+)/$ /index.php?page=$1&comp=$2    [QSA]
```

However, I need to prevent a specific folder from redirecting, lets call it /folder/

I can't seem to get it to work correctly and hope someone can help.

THanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add at the top:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/ - [L,NC]
```