# Allow subfolders along with website with .htaccess of Ghost installation

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

In my Ghost installation on server I want to access a few folders and subfolders, but the main ghost setup's htaccess prevents that. I don't understand htaccess at all. What rewrite rules should be used to allow a few subfolders.

example.nl should be accessible along with all permalinks. Then a particular folder with a few subfolders need to open when path is requested from browser. That's not happening right now. I will need to load index.html files with all css and js etc.

*Example:* example.nl/subfolder/sub1/index.html

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes

IndexIgnore *

DirectoryIndex 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
# Simple URL redirect:
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.nl:62254/$1 [P]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Assuming that we're not talking about a dead relative that's haunting you - what's Ghost?

Comment: It's a CMS. 
https://ghost.org/
The question is basically about htaccess and I don't know how to go about changing them. Any pointers?

Comment: Google something simple like "stop htaccess redirect for specific folders", which leads you to stuff like http://stackoverflow.com/q/17350598/1427878 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/163302/1427878